# Value in Texbox1 have to search all other Textbox available in the Form and change backcolor

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Could somebody provide with sample data on my requirement.

I have one main textbox with a date in the format: `dd-mm-yyyy` there is another 42 textboxes with date of format: `dd`.

I want to check if the value in main textbox matches any of the other 42 textboxes in form. If there is match found, I want the `Backcolor` of the matching textbox to change to Orange or Red in colour.

Comment: You only want to check the days value?

Comment: Yes i want to check the days value.